# Google Maps API TypeError window.Image is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had a google map running in an old content management system running JScript front ends calling a PHP API to fulfill requests.  Everything was working fine, although after the V3 Google Maps API is now producing `TypeError window.Image is not a function`.

The following trace is from Google Chrome Browser

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.Image is not a function
k3  @   stats.js:2

Uncaught TypeError: window.Image is not a function
vB  @   util.js:9
```

This is the JScript to load the map

```
setMap: function(){ 
        this._map = new google.maps.Map(this._panel.mapcanvas, {
            zoom: 16,
            center: this._latlng
        });
    },
```

The Map takes ages to load, wont zoom, shows no controls.
The Map initialises at zoom level 16 and centers to the `_latlng` provided.

If I add any other controls to the map options, they do not show, no changes to the map at all.

The `window.Image` problem presents itself on initial load as well.

```
rg  @   js?key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap:84
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks to those that edited the code space.  First question on this site, first time ive used it.  Much appreciated.  Sharing is caring.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:
Somewhere on your page a global variable called `Image` will be created(and it's not a function).

This variable overwrites the built-in function [`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) (the maps-API tries to call this function)

Demo:

```js
      Image='something';


      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html ,body,#map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 ;}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div><script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3">
    </script>
```

Solution:remove the creation of this variable(e.g. use another name), you never should use names for global variables which are equal to names of built-in properties of the window-object

Comment: The Variable Image is in the Google API Code

Comment: The API tries to access it, but did not set it. It must have been overwritten somewhere in your page.

Comment: After much screwing around, this is the correct answer.  I had a var Image that was holding some image data, upon finding this var and changing it to imagedata, the google maps API loads fast and is doing what it is supposed to do.  It is a clash between the var defined in my code vs the var defined in the Google code.